# JVM and hardware interactions profiling

Tags: java, jvm, profiling, intel, cpu-cache

**Hi.**
I searched for a while and stumbled about the lack of specific instrument. There're many good, even free profilers for Java, which allow to see how much time the code parts took overall, but nothing for the next tasks.

#### Given.

A Java multithreading program, doing some calculations through the misc.unsafe, using a simple fork-join pool, ThreadPoolExecutor, running on one Oracle JVM and Intel Xeon based server-class node. Looks like nothing hard, hot-spots are obvious. I need to figure out is any optimizations possible, which are promising and their potential assessment.

#### Needed.

For this, among the other information, I need a decent information about what exactly happens inside the hardware. For the research start, I want at least the cache misses and memory boundary overhead, byte-code or hardware instructions' overall timings. This would be very useful for avoiding "box ticking" approach. For clarification what exactly I need, I put here a similar instrument's wiki link which I used for a C or Fortran legacy code https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VTune (*especially look briefly at the "Hardware event sampling" paragraph*) and it fulfilled all my purposes.

*Thanks in advance.*

Comment: Why don't you use VTune if it has everything you need? AFAIK, it also supports Java.

Comment: I'm seeking another way, while trying to start that bundle. One more detail, from the documents seems, there isn't a byte-code - instructions - cpu ticks linkage, so I can divide the measures only at methods' level (this  restriction may become too rough for this well optimized code).

Comment: see https://github.com/jrudolph/perf-map-agent and http://psy-lob-saw.blogspot.de/2015/07/jmh-perfasm.html

Comment: You can also look at jit watch to see what native instruction come from bytes code and java code.